# Transfer session from script to firefox

Tags: python, session, firefox, ui-automation

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I have a python script that opens a webpage, gets a `jsessionid`, then posts username and password and the `jsessionid` and receives back a new `jsessionid` along with the 'main' page.  So far, everything is cool.

Thing is, now I want the script to open a browser (Firefox) and continue the session from that moment on.  Problem is, if I just send an os command to open firefox with the url, it just opens the login page, because the `jsessionid` is not transferred.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The python library [spynner](https://code.google.com/p/spynner/) is great for programmatically executing a browser.

```
import spynner

browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.load('http://www.google.com')
browser.create_webview()
browser.show()  # Launches windowed browser in your OS
```

Comment: Actually I'm working in an environment where I can't install anything new, so I should just stick to the standard python libraries :(